# Layout views below another programmatically created views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a screen, which contains multiple UIImages (their amount and size are known only at runtime, so i add them programmatically) and some fixed buttons below these UIImages.

How to make buttons display certainly under all Images?

I've tried

**1.)** Put Buttons and Images into 2 separate views, and then add constraint between them. No result, buttons are hidden behind images.
**2.)** Put buttons into separate view and set constraint in code, (tried both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear). Constraint is set between container view and top of the screen, depending on size and amount of images.
Example of code:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSInteger totalImages = [self.object.fullphotos count];
    self.labelsTopConstraint.constant = totalImages*(imageHeight + 20) + 10;
}
```

In case 2 buttons are positioned right, but don't respond to touches.

How should I layout everything correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a Tableview for those images and add buttons in a last cell.

Comment: Thank you, used a tableView and put every image or button in separate cell.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is creating a Object with a refresh method that can be called in viewDidAppear

MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageview *img;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *btn;
- (void) refresh;
```

in MyObject.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


- (void) refresh {
     //make your settings here
}

-(void)myMethod {
    //your button action here
}
```

Then in your controller if you have your objects in an NSArray:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    for (MyObject *myObj in objectsArray) {
        @autoreleasePool {
            [myObj refresh];
        }
    }
}
```